# PVFS2 on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing

is it possible to install PVFS2/OrangeFS on a Raspberry Pi cluster?
I already installed it on Linux but i really dont know how to install it on a Raspberry. Anyone got an idea or is it simple as installing it on the build system?